# Add multiple folders in one zip file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, zip

Perhaps my question can be a duplicate, but I'm new in powershell, and cannot figure out, what is wrong with my script, that zipping particular directories:

```
$path = "C:\backup\DEV82" 
if(!(Test-Path -Path $path )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $path
}

cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev82\


$SOURCE = Get-ChildItem * -Directory|Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "App_Config|Resources|bin"}

$dtstamp = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
Foreach ($s in $SOURCE)
{
    $DESTINATION = Join-path -path $path -ChildPath "$dtstamp.zip"
    If(Test-path $DESTINATION) {
        Remove-item $DESTINATION
    }
    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($s.fullname, $DESTINATION)
}
```

If I execute command in `$SOURCE` variable, it gathers all required directories, which I want zip http://prntscr.com/j0sqri

$DESTINATION also returns valid value

```
PS C:\> $DESTINATION
C:\backup\DEV82\20180404_223153.zip
```

but right now only last folder (Resources) exists in zip file.

Comment: `"$($dtstamp.zip).zip` -the variable has no property `.zip` so that will evaluate to `$null`. Change to `"$dtstamp.zip"`. (And, same with @boxdog's answer and $s.fullname).

Comment: Use some error trapping to figure out the values causing you errors: `try { [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($s.fullname, $DESTINATION) } catch { "Arg1: $($s.fullname)"; "Arg2: $DESTINATION"; throw }`.

Comment: I reworked script - fixed $dtstamp in zip filename and removed Select-Object from the pipeline, but right now, only last folder remains in zip file. It seems, that after each loop, it removes zip, and recreates new with same name and next folder. Is there any way to add folders in existing zip file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I rewrite my script, using, instead of Zipfile class, Compress-Archive with -Update ( -Update allows to add files\folders into existing archive )

```
$path = "C:\backup\DEV82" 
if(!(Test-Path -Path $path )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $path
}

cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev82\
$SOURCE = Get-ChildItem * -Directory|Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "App_Config|Resources|bin"}

$dtstamp = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
$DESTINATION = Join-path -path $path -ChildPath "$dtstamp.zip"
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
If(Test-path $DESTINATION) {
    Remove-item $DESTINATION
}

Foreach ($s in $SOURCE)
{
Compress-Archive -Path $s.fullname -DestinationPath $DESTINATION -Update
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$SOURCE` is already just a list of folder names, so you don't need the `FullName` property here:

```
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($s.fullname, $DESTINATION)
```

Either remove it, or remove the `Select-Object` from the pipeline here:

```
$SOURCE = Get-ChildItem * -Directory | 
            Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "App_Config|Resources|bin"} |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: Tried to change string on:
    
    [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($s, $DESTINATION)

No success. Will try with second variant

Comment: Works for me, though I also notice that you have an extra '.zip' in side the subexpression here: "$($dtstamp.zip).zip"

Comment: Ok, I reworked script - fixed $dtstamp in zip filename and removed `Select-Object` from the pipeline, but right now, only last folder remains in zip file. It seems, that after each loop, it removes zip, and recreates new with same name and next folder.

Comment: To be honest, I've never used the ZipFile class, but it's likely it is just over-writing any existing zip file each time around your loop.  An alternative you could investigate is the Compress-Archive cmdlet.